# How can I add a simple node creation form to a page?

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I'm trying to add a formspring-like page to my website. This looks like an easy task for Drupal 7: create a new content type, create a new view to list the questions and answers, add another view to the backend to view the unanswered questions, and you're ready to go.

But I have one remaining problem: how can I add a simple form to ask a new question? I want to have a simple form on top of the list-page, with just 1 input box where a visitor can ask his question and a submit button.

I've already found the "form block"-module, but I can't trim the output of the form to just 1 input box. Is there an off-the-shelf solution, or do I have to create a custom module/block that programmatically creates a new node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way I can see this being possible, would be creating a custom node/add page for your content (see [How can I theme the template for edit or add a node for a specific content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538600/how-can-i-theme-the-template-for-edit-or-add-a-node-for-a-specific-content-type)) and then using Panels to create a custom page with your node on top and then your view directly below.

I would be interested to know if anyone else has any better/easier suggestions of course. +1 for question :)

Comment: also note that submitting the form from the add part of page would redirect you to that content, so you would need a way of overriding this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As no one seems to have a better solution, I'm accepting yours.